# Error with the download button in SHINY

Tags: r, csv, shiny, export-to-csv

My download button is showing an error when I use it to retrieve my report. The output id for the button is downloadData. What seems to be the error?

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste('Final Report', '.csv', sep='')
  },
content = function(file){
       write.csv(csv_write,row.names=FALSE, na="")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html):

```
content = function(file) {
  write.csv(data, file)
}
```

So you also have to pass the file parameter to the write.csv function. Assuming the data you want to write is called `csv_write`, you should do:

```
write.csv(csv_write, file, row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

---

**Working example**

```
library(shiny)

csv_write = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,2,3))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Final Report', '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(csv_write,file,row.names=FALSE, na="")
    })


})

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(

      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download data')

))

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Note that is csv_write is a reactive or reactiveValue, you should call csv_write() instead of csv_write.

Comment: The file which I am downloading is coming in the name of downloadData and not final report. That file is also not in csv format

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: The error in the code above is that the file which I am downloading is not in the name of Final report and the extension is not in csv. Why do you think this problem exists?

Comment: it is very hard to understand what do You mean. The name Final report is the name which You give/ set to name the downloaded data, and `.csv` means that You want to get the csv formatted data at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that should work for You assuming that csv_write is the dataset which You wanna download:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        "Final_Report.csv", content = function(file) {
         write.csv(csv_write, file, row.names=FALSE, na="")
        }
      )
```

and first of all what kind of Error do You get?

Comment: The file which I am downloading is coming in the name of downloadData and not final report. That file is also not in csv format